# set/unset checkboxes in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, checkbox

i've got one problem with checkboxes in JSF.
I want them to behave dependently on each other, e.g., when i check a box which belongs to some object that has children then all checkboxes that belong to these children components must be checked either. And also when i uncheck one of child's checkbox the parent should be unchecked too. It's pretty simple with plain HTML/javascript, but i can't do anything with this under JSF. For some reason i can't set ID's for them because all checkboxes are rendered dynamically in a treetable and it prevents me from setting my own ID's, i.e. whatever i set in ID property only constant part will apply, all dynamic data that i pass is ignored. 
I tried to do it through valueChangeListener or validator but in both cases after i set needed values something sets them back! I don't know who does it and i can't do anything with this. Here's some code (i use OpenFaces treeTable):

```
<o:treeTable id="instTreeTable" var="inst" ...>
<...>
    <o:column id="isGranted" width="10%">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.access_granted}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox 
                value="#{inst.assignedToUser}" 
                styleClass="treeTableText"
                valueChangeListener="#{MbUserInstitutions.onAccessGrantedChanged}"
                >
            <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="instTreeTable"/>
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </o:column>
<...>
</o:treeTable>
```

MbUserInstitutions:

```
public void onAccessGrantedChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Boolean granted = (Boolean) event.getNewValue();
    Institution inst = getInstitution();
    if (granted.booleanValue() && inst.hasChildren()) {
        setChildrenInsts(inst);
    } else if (!granted.booleanValue() && inst.getParentId() != null){
        unsetParentInst(inst);
    }
}

private Institution getInstitution() {
    return (Institution) Faces.var("inst");
}

private void setChildrenInsts(Institution parent) {
        for (Institution child: parent.getChildren()) {
            child.setAssignedToUser(true);
            if (child.hasChildren()) {
                setChildrenInsts(child);
            }
        }
}

private void unsetParentInst(Institution child) {
    child.setAssignedToUser(false);

        for (Institution inst: coreInsts) {
            if (inst.getId().equals(child.getParentId())) {
                unsetParentInst(inst);
                break;
            }
        }
}
```